# How can I test the angular-ui-tinymce inside a tabset with Plunker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to test out angular-ui-tinymce by setting this up inside a Plunkr. Can someone show me how I can bring together the files for angular-ui-tinymce into the plunkr so I can demonstrate the functionality.

So far I have the following plunker to demonstrate tabs:

http://plnkr.co/edit/g1mJEAYt4dI6a0Q0m7X6?p=preview

I cannot seem to find any Plunker demo of angular-ui-tinymce and would appreciate guidance as to how I could add to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not including the right JS files here.

Note that Angular UI bootstrap JS file didn't include the ui-tinymce module. So as a first step , remove the Angular JS bootstrap module and include the ui-tinymce JS file which is avaiable in Github.

Secondly, the angular-tinymce module has a dependency on the original core tinymce.js file. So you've include that js file also.

I actually forked your plunkr and fixed these issues. Please see the code and find the changes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6OpbZM?p=preview

( There was a script file loading issue in Plunkr when I try to fetch directly from Github, So I included that ui-tinymce.js as a local file )

Comment: I checked out your work. Thank you for your help including all that's needed for tinymce. However now I cannot see the tabs. Are the tab filesloaded correctly?

Comment: Tabs were part of the Angular-Bootstrap JS file. I removed that js file for now. When we re-include that JS file, It should reappear.

Comment: Hi Shidhin - Can you add that back to the Plunkr so others could maybe benefit if they see your answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I will accept your answer as it was the first. Can you maybe vote for dcodesmith as he also helped but was just a couple minutes slower. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a few files.

1. The TinyMce Script itself `<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>`
2. The Angular-ui [tinymce directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/src/tinymce.js)
3. injecting the directive into your app `var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.tinymce'])`

Here's the solved [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RluHky2FA8iCxHlp2sI7?p=preview)